# Domain of the function $f(x) = \frac1{(x^2-1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I've been asked to write the domain of the function $f(x) = \frac1{(x^2-1)}$. 
Its domain would be: $(-\infty, -1)$ $\cup$ $(-1, 1)$ $\cup$ $(1, \infty)$. Have I written down the correct domain of the function?

Comment: Yes, you are.${}$

Comment: You could also write it as R\{-1,1}

Comment: yes you can write R-{+1,-1}too

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestions.

Comment: @DavidMitra I've expanded my question, please reread it.

Comment: *Maximal* domain w.r.t. the *reals*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have written your answer correctly. It can alternatively be written as $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \not= \pm1\}$ You can see why this is through a graph. Notice that there is an asymptote at $1$ and $-1$ because that is when the function becomes undefined. However, it is not necessary for a function to have an asymptote to be undefined. [image]

Comment: @Abel Sorry about that, I noticed that I had typed in the wrong function. I have corrected my post.

Comment: @Abel I have corrected that also :) I have put $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \not=1,-1\}$

Comment: Now it's completely correct as far as I can see :). +1

Comment: There are functions which are not defined at $\pm 1$ without vertical asymptotes there.